# Ajax reload all X seconds - datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

i use this piece of code:

```
setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload(function ( json ) {
        if(json=="")
            {
             $('#newUpdate').val("No Updates available");
            }
        else
            {
             $('#newUpdate').val( json.lastInput );
            }

    });
    }, 30000 );
```

The update works fine.
But if i have no update the 'newUpdate' div should show the above text'No Updates available'. But it dosen´t work. 
If i use 'json.equals("") than it´s freezing... Oo
What is wrong, can someone help me out:)

Thanks

Comment: A sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help. With just this part of js, it's hard to know what's going on. And if you tagged it as databases, you should provide the server-side code block, which sends you json data.

Comment: Why don't you add console.log(json) and see on the browser console what it's returning at each time so you can do the correct comparation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
setInterval( function () {
table.ajax.reload(function ( json ) {
    if(json=="")
        {
         $('#newUpdate').text("No Updates available");
        }
    else
        {
         $('#newUpdate').text( json.lastInput );
        }

});
}, 30000 );
```

A div has no value. You can also use something like:

```
$('#newUpdate').html('<div style="color:red">No Updates available</div>');
```

If you want to style your output.

Comment: Then mark is as answered. This is common practice here, so that users with the same issue will know which is the right solution.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Since you are new here, take the two minutes to make the beginners tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour You will get a badge for it :-)

Comment: See? 2 Badges and rep up. Keep on going this way and other users are more keen to help you out instead of downvoting you.